# Taking frame one by one from a video .3gpp format in opencv

Tags: java, android, video, frame, javacv

As some one suggested in stackoverflow, i tried the code to take frames one by one from a video as follows:

```
String STR=(String) Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

FrameGrabber videoGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(STR+"/vd.3gpp");
           try 
            {
                videoGrabber.setFormat("video format goes here");
                videoGrabber.start();    
            } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
            {           
                Log.e("javacv", "Failed to start grabber" + e);     
                return ;  
            }


            Frame vFrame = null;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    vFrame = videoGrabber.grabFrame();
                    if(vFrame != null);
                        //do your magic here
                } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e("javacv", "video grabFrame failed: "+ e);
                }
            }while(vFrame != null);

            try 
            {
                videoGrabber.stop();
            }catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("javacv", "failed to stop video grabber", e);
                return ;
            }
```

But i am getting unexpectedly can't able to run app. Can anybody suggest me the solution to get all frames from a stored video?

Comment: Even I haven't found a solution to this. Let me know if you have.

Comment: Any progress on this?